# python pymssql error: 18456, b'DB-Lib error message 20010, severity 8:\nUnable to allocate sufficient memory

Tags: python, pymssql

I use `pymssql` to connect the `sql` server database with `macOS`,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pymssql
conn = pymssql.connect(host='', port=1433, user='', password='', database='', charset='gbk')
```

if I set charset with `'utf8'`, it come out with error connection failed, if I set charset with 'gbk', it come out with `error` as below:

```
18456, b'DB-Lib error message 20010, severity 8:\nUnable to allocate sufficient memory
```

Where I use `navicat` to connect this `sql` server database work well.

Answer (score 0):

When I removed the `charset` option, it worked.

The version info is:

SQL Server-2014

pymssql 2.2.1

OS win server 2012 r2